# How to format an integer in python with limited significant figures AND thousands separators

Tags: python, python-3.x

Task: format a (large) integer in python with limited significant figures and thousands separators.

For example, turn

```
791075165588
```

into

```
791,000,000,000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution I can find is:

```
print('{:,}'.format( int( float ('%.3g' % 791075165588 ) ) )   )
```

Output:

```
791,000,000,000
```

Replace the `3` with the desired number of significant figures.

Alternative approach with numpy:

```
print(   '{:,}'.format(  (lambda n, f : np.round(n, f - len(str(abs(int(n)))) ) ) (791075165588 , 3)   )    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have already a solution working for your own purposes. If someone would want to choose significant figures from the nearest thousands/millions, rather than choosing the number of significant figures, they could do this:

```
import numpy as np
mynumber = 791075165588

print(f'Rounding to -9 means billions, for instance {np.round(mynumber, -9):,}')
```

```
Rounding to -9 means billions, for instance 791,000,000,000
```

That was limited to the billions significant figures.

Comment: This is nice, you can do it like this: print(   f'{np.round(791075165588, -4):,}'   )